# find matching string in two strings

Tags: string, perl, substring

I would like to get hints for a perl script that finds the longest common substring present in two strings. Each string is maximal 500 characters long.

For example

```
abcsffwqfwqsdfasdfTHISISANAPPLEfasdfasdfsdfsadfasdfsdaf4353.54.4fdfsdgg
detertqteqtTHISISANAPPLEafsedfgwetwqrgtwrgtwetpqw4t5osdavm\wert4384..53
```

The output should be `THISISANAPPLE`

Sounds easy, but may not be trivial.

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: Where is your code? Where is your idea? What have you done so far? This is not a code writing service.

Comment: 1. My approach so far is the following. Take substrings of 10 characters in a loop from one string and look from them in the other string (shorter than 1o character matches are discarded). 2. Mark the starting positions of the matching string in both strings. 3. Try to extend the hits by adding successively one character till a mismatch or end of string is found. 3. Chose the longest hit. I am not sure if this is the best, fastest option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [String::LCSS_XS](http://search.cpan.org/~limaone/String-LCSS_XS-1.2/lib/String/LCSS_XS.pm)

```
use String::LCSS_XS 'lcss';

my ($s1,$s2) = (
  "abcsffwqfwqsdfasdfTHISISANAPPLEfasdfasdfsdfsadfasdfsdaf4353.54.4fdfsdgg",
  "detertqteqtTHISISANAPPLEafsedfgwetwqrgtwrgtwetpqw4t5osdavm\wert4384..53"
);
my $longest = lcss ($s1, $s2);
print "$longest\n";
```

output

```
THISISANAPPLE
```